# Construct form from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a `queryset` in a particular view :

```
class SomeView(View)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        objs = SomeModel.objects.all()
```

Now I somehow want this to be displayed as a form of `objs` with checkboxes.

Also the `queryset` might not be `SomeModel.objects.all()` always. It might change in the view depending on the request.

Which is the best way to achieve  this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the ModelMultipleChoiceField does. You can use it in conjunction with the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget to get what you want.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                      queryset=SomeModel.objects.all(),
                      widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

**Edit**

To change the queryset depending on a value, you need to override `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    model_value = kwargs.pop('my_value', None)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if model_value is not None:
        self.fields['my_choices'].queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(my_field=my_value)
```

Comment: Ok but I am confused.How do change the queryset depending on some id ?
So my queryset will  not always be `SomeModel.objects.all()` It might also be `SomeModel.objects.filter(id=23)` . Were id will change depending on the request.

Comment: Thanks. Got it now.Changed my question.